# How to bring layer to top faster when there are dozens of layers?

Tags: arcgis-pro, layers

[image]

In the image you can see that I have map pages overlapping each other.

I would like to bring the bottom map to the top so I can see the whole page.

Dragging and dropping takes for ever because I have ~100 pages.

What's the fastest way to bring layer to top in my case?

I know that you can just drag drop to the top of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the layers you want to "jump over: Mark all, expect the one at the bottom > right click > Group Selected. Even if you have dozens of layers, they are now collapsed to one single group.

Now it's easy to simply drag and drop the remaining layer from the bottom to the top.

*Be aware that you can create as many groups and sub-groups (inside a group) as you want to organize the layer panel.*

Comment: This is definitely an improvement but is there not a way I can right select the layer on the map and send to top like I can in AutCAD?

Comment: This is probably possible with Python, you should then specifically ask for that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Be aware that this site requires you to include code to Python questions. Maybe have a look to other questions here to find out the basics of addressing groups and the layer order or see if someone can help. I don't know enough Python to help you with this, unfortunatley. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, to reduce the "distance" you have to drag your bottom layer over, you can also select each layer except the bottom one, then hold ctrl and click the arrow to minimize/collapse the entries for the others layers in the Contents pane. Collapsing all these entries will reduce the distance you need to drag your layer of interest by 80%, since you will no longer see lines for RGB, Red, Green, and Blue.